# MATLAB: How do I save an axes that is generated within a GUI to a '.fig' file?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have created a GUI programmatically in MATLAB which allows the user to adjust certain parameters to change the data shown on an axes. I would like the user to be able to save that axes as a MATLAB figure. I have tried multiple methods found via Google and the MATLAB documentation, but none have worked.

My current non-working code:

```
% Creation of the axes ui component
a1 = axes('Units','pixels','Position',[20,18,270,255],'box','on');

% Skipped ahead to callback for 'save' menu item
function menu1_callback(~,~)
    % Creates a new figure
    f2 = figure;
    % Copies the axes a1 to the new figure
    copyobj(a1,f2);
    % Save the new figure
    saveas(gcf,'filename','fig');
end
```

This is the error MATLAB generates:

```
Error using getProxyValueFromHandle (line 15)
Input must be a valid handle.

Error in plotedit (line 91)
                [varargout{1:nargout}] = feval(args{:});

Error in specgraph.barseries/preserialize (line 10)
peerVals = plotedit({'getProxyValueFromHandle',hPeers});

Error in hgsaveStructDbl (line 80)
        olddata{i} = {hh,preserialize(hh)};

Error in hgsave (line 62)
    hgS = hgsaveStructDbl(h, SaveAll);

Error in saveasfig (line 7)
hgsave( h, name );

Error in saveas (line 126)
    feval( ['saveas' format], h, name )

Error in GBdataVisualiser2/menu1_callback (line 165)
        saveas(gcf,'filename','fig');

Error while evaluating uimenu Callback
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are passing the wrong handle to the function `saveas`. I think the function `gcf` only works when you are dealing with normal figures, that open in separate screens, and not figures that are embedded on GUIs.

I would try:

```
% Skipped ahead to callback for 'save' menu item
function menu1_callback(~,~)
    % Creates a new figure
    f2 = figure;
    % Copies the axes a1 to the new figure
    copyobj(a1,f2);
    % Save the new figure
    saveas(f2,'filename','fig');
end
```

Comment: I'm afraid that produces a near identical error that differs only by the change in code:

`Error in GBdataVisualiser2/menu1_callback (line 165)
        saveas(f2,'filename','fig'); `